# IOS HttpPost with parameters

Tags: ios, cookies, http-post, httpclient

I want to send http post with parameters and then retrieve cookies from response.

In android I use the following:

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://stackoverflow.com/");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1); 
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("parameter", parameter));  
request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

List<Cookie> cookies = client.getCookieStore().getCookies();
```

I tried to use the following in IOS but it did not work for me:

```
NSURL *authUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:authUrl];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString * parameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"login=%@&password=%@",login,password];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[parameters UTF8String] length:[parameters length]];
[request setHTTPBody:requestData];
[request setTimeoutInterval:15.0];
NSURLConnection * connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

In delegate method I receive the data. But the data look like the post have been sent without parameters. It sends the link but does not sends the parameters, I guess. I also tried to setup a header and it didn't help me.

```
[request addValue:VALUE forHTTPHeaderField:@"login"];
```

And use of `sendSynchronousRequest` didn't help either.

```
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Depending on what the login and password parameters are this line won't work properly: 'NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[parameters UTF8String] length:[parameters length]];' as the calculated length could be wrong. Is the error you get a validation error from the server?

Comment: Everything is working (length is correct). There is no a validation error from the server. But it is not sending the parameters properly. I am getting the same web-content as I sent url without parameters.

Comment: How have you proved that everything is working? Have you verified the request data that is actually sent (detected using a proxy) or checked the data received at the server?

Comment: Finally I've done with it. The problem was with authUrl. I missed "/" in the end of url. That's why server received right parameters but didn't do nothing with them. So this code works if someone is need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source works correctly, but I was sending request to the wrong website.